# Input fields issue on prepend in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress

I am working on a meta fields in `WordPress`. The scenario is, there is a question field and its answer field, Like this:

[image]

When I click on plus sign the answer field add successfully with `prepend`.

But I face an issue with prepend. When I enter a value in answer field and click on plus the input field in which I enter the value does not goes down but new field prepend blew, Like this:

[image]

[js Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/deemi/g54r88we/4/)

I want, that when I enter the brown and click on plus sign the brown goes down and first on is empty, Like This:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not adding value in the input field while appending.

```
var result_a = jQuery('#qs_survey_a').val();
​
        jQuery('.multi_fields_wrap').prepend('<div class="multi_fields"><input type="text" name="qs_survey_a[]" id="qs_survey_a" value="' + result_a + '"><a href="#" class="qs_cross">x</a></div>');
```

First get the value of input field and then add that value while appending the new row. You can also clear the input field after the prepending event takes place by adding this simple line

```
        jQuery('.your_input_class').val("");
```

Hope That Helps

Answer (score 1):

You have to use append instead of prepend like below code. Because, prepend add the field first.

```
jQuery('.qs_btn').click(function () {
      jQuery('.multi_fields_wrap').append('<div class="multi_fields"><input type="text" name="qs_survey_a[]" id="qs_survey_a"><a href="#" class="qs_cross">x</a></div>');
      return false;
});
```

Comment: I don't want to use this ... this also give me weird issue

Comment: Actually what is your expected output?

Answer (score 1):

What i have understood after reading the OP and comments, your expected output might come after altering the html part only.
Have a look

```
<div class="multi_fields_wrap">
  <input type="text" name="qs_survey_a[]" id="qs_survey_a" value="">
</div>
```